# Sorting Linux ps command

Tags: linux, ps

I am trying to print a process tree of only my login on a Linux server. I have used:

```
ps -e --forest
```

to print the process tree, but it gives the process tree of all other users in Linux. What can I do to sort only my own login's process tree?

Also, What are the command line argument(s) for ps to see all of my own login’s running threads?
I've tried:

```
ps -l
```

and I only see 2 threads running. Is this the right command?
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering by user will show you all the selected user’s processes:

```
ps -u thecoder --forest
```

will show you all `thecoder`’s processes (and only those), in forest layout;

```
ps -u thecoder -l
```

will show all the threads.

Comment: See also `pstree "$LOGNAME"` where available (and various options to get more info about the processs).